# Calculate time taken by 100 static select statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to calculate time taken by multiple static select statements. I see output file with each select statement output but unfortunately nothing else. No print output, no timestamp value either. Below is script template. Suggestions?
Here is how I am running script:

```bash
mssql-cli -i /tmp/query.sql -o /tmp/query_output
```

```sql
declare @StartTime DateTime = GETDATE()
print @StartTime
select * from <table1> where PK_ID='<value_1>'
select * from <table1> where PK_ID='<value_2>'
select * from <table2> where PK_ID='<value_3>'
select * from <table2> where PK_ID='<value_4>'
select * from <table3> where PK_ID='<value_5>'
declare @endTime DateTime = GETDATE()
print 'MAY BE NULL '+ ISNULL((@endTime - @StartTime),'NULL') ;
```

Comment: `mssql-cli` is deprecated, I wouldn't suggest using it. Use the new sqlcmd ([go-sqlcmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/tools/sqlcmd/go-sqlcmd-utility)) instead, like the [deprecation notice](https://github.com/dbcli/mssql-cli/blob/main/README.md) states.

Comment: Are you trying to tell the elapsed time between those two dates? subtracting a date from another date will yield a date. try using `datediff` with a granularity you are interested in. For example: `concat('MAY BE NULL ', isnull(datediff(ms, @endTime, @StartTime),'NULL'))`

Comment: @Xedni unfortunately I tried but it doesn't print either.

Comment: What happens when you run it in SSMS (or ADS)? If you see the printed messages there, then it's likely what @ThomA said, and you should switch to sqlcmd. I don't have mssql-cli installed on my machine, but I was able to test an analogous statement to what you're trying to do using sqlcmd, and I saw all the printed messages.

Comment: I *couldn't* install `mssql-cli`, as it was deprecated there wasn't a release 22.04 jammy.

Comment: Just turn your print to SELECT (select getdate() as start_time as first code line and select getdate() as end_time as the last line) and then manually calculate the difference, but attention, you are not measuring time taken to execute but the time taken to get the output to client